# Why can't the zero vector be the smallest subspace containing a plane and a line through (0,0,0)?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

From Strang's book, exercise 3.1.16:

I understand that a plane yields 2 basis vectors, and that the line could yield a third basis vector if the line is not on the plane. Therefore, two possible subspaces could be the plane (if the line is on the plane) or $\mathbb{R}^3$. In the answer, he says these are the two smallest subspaces.

However, my confusion arises from a previous statement he does in his book when he describes a subspace $\bf{S}$ of the vector space $\bf{V}$ containing all vectors $\vec{v}$ perpendicular to $\vec{u} = (1,2,1)$. In particular, he says that c$\vec{x}$, where $\vec{x} = (0,0,0)$ and c is some constant (so, all the multiples of the zero vector) is the  smallest subspace.

Then, why can't the zero vector be an answer for the question?

Comment: "he says that $c\vec{x}$" what does this mean? do you mean $c\vec{x} = \text{ something}$? edit: it is like saying "he says that $5$", doesn't make sense

Comment: zero vector is an answer to what question? If you mean the title, then zero space certainly does not contain a plane nor a line

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee, I meant all the multiples of the zero vector. He says that this is the smallest subspace for that vector space.

Comment: @Roedor90 Ah, ok

Comment: @user340297, I agree with you. That's why I'm confused about the assertion he makes about all multiples of the zero vector being the smallest subspace of $\bf{V}$

Comment: You seem to be working from Strang's "Introduction to Linear Algebra", possibly the 3rd edition.  I can't find the example with "a subspace $\bf{S}$ of the vector space $\bf{V}$ containing all vectors $\vec{v}$ perpendicular to $\vec{u} = (1,2,1)$."  Can you confirm the edition (3rd) and give a section / page no?